Ubuntu installation freezing in VirtualBox
I'm installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS in VirtualBox 7.0. The installation was proceeding normally, until it froze ("Copiando arquivos" means "Copying files").

Specs:
  Host: Windows 10
  VirtualBox version: 7.0.18
  Ubuntu version: 24.04 LTS
  RAM: 2048 MB
  CPUs: 2
  Video memory: 128 MB
  Graphics controller: VMSVGA
  3D Acceleration: Enabled
  Size in virtual disk: 2,2 TB

(This may not fix the issue) Please allocate at least 4 GB of RAM. That is the minimum system requirements.

That is not really enough RAM.
Also, you may find that it is worth disabling 3D passthrough until the OS installation is complete and you have installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions.
On some host OSes and some host graphics chipsets, 3D passthrough can be unstable. This sounds like it could be your problem. You can set the graphics to VirtualBox for simplicty, install, and then shut down the VM and change them to a guest GPU that supports 3D passthrough after you have installed and updated the OS.

I had the same problem on a Windows 11 host. My Ubuntu installations (desktop and server) would always freeze and, usually, I couldn't even get the installer to start. This surprised me using Ubuntu server because I thought I was having a GUI problem with desktop but ended up with the same installation woes with server.
What ended up working for me was the following. Sorry, I don't have screenshots. I'll probably catch flak for the answer not having step-by-step instructions, but I'm using an Ubuntu workstation at the moment without access to my Windows system.

I had to search for Windows features and disable anything that had to do with Hyper-V or Virtualization.
I went into Defender and disabled Core Isolation (more on that here).

After a reboot, I was consistently able to install and use Ubuntu (desktop and server) without freezes or black screens. I also don't get the green turtle (software virtualization) in the bottom-right area of the window but, instead, I got the blue V (hardware virtualization) and a very noticeable improvement in snappiness and perceived speed.
I don't leave my Windows settings that way as Core Isolation and Virtualization-based Security provide security benefits in Windows. I turn it off when I'm using one of my VMs and turn it back on when finished (both require a reboot).
This may not fix your situation but I hope it helps.
Edit: Also, yes, needs more RAM :)
